# Composer: looking for namespaced class in multiple locations

Tags: php, oop, composer-php

I'm trying to figure out how to get composer to look for classes for a specific namespace under 2 directories. What I'm thinking of is this:

```
Default location:   /src/MyModule/myClass.php
Override location:  /config/override/MyModule/myClass.php
```

Now, I'd like to use composer to configure the autoloader to check if a class exists under the Override location. If it does, use this class. If not, load the class from the default location.

Is this possible using composer or would I have to implement this logic using my own autoloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4):

> If you need to search for a same prefix in multiple directories, you
>   can specify them as an array as such:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Monolog\\": ["src/", "lib/"] }
    }
}
```

You would add that to your `composer.json` file of course. To do it programatically you can do this:

```
$autoloader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$autoloader->addPsr4('MyModule\\', [ '/first/dir/MyModule', '/another/dir/MyModule' ]);
```